# Animate blurRadius property with react-native

Tags: animation, react-native, react-animated

I started to animate an image in my react-native project but somehow I can't animate the `blurRadius` property. `Translate` and `Scale` are working just fine.
Here is the code I use to `interpolat`e values for blur, scale and translate :

```
// Compute image position
const imageTranslate = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
  inputRange: [-IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT, 0, IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT],
  outputRange: [IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT / 2, 0, -IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT / 3],
  extrapolate: 'clamp',
});
// Compute image blur
const imageBlur = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT],
  outputRange: [0, 100],
  extrapolate: 'clamp',
});
// Compute image scale
const imageScale = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
  inputRange: [-IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT, 0, IMAGE_MAX_HEIGHT],
  outputRange: [2, 1, 1],
  extrapolate: 'clamp',
});
```

And this is my Image :

```
return (
  <Animated.Image
    blurRadius={imageBlur}
    source={this.props.imgSrc}
    style={[
      animatedImageStyles.backgroundImage,
      { transform: [{ translateY: imageTranslate }, { scale: imageScale }] }
    ]}
  />
);
```

I binded the `this.state.scrollY` value on a `ScrollView` scroll.

Comment: Animating blurRadius kind of works in 0.51 but I'm getting some serious performance issues with Android in particular.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener to get animated blur value and change the state. Then put your `blurValue` state in `blurRadius` prop.

```
this.state.blurAnimation.addListener(({value}) => this.setState({blurValue:value}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The timing of your issue indicates that the solution should be as simple as upgrading React Native. Blur radius support on images was added in version 0.46. I have just created a new react-native app and implemented 3 animations on an image, one of which was blurRadius, and everything works fine. This is with version 0.49.5. Upgrading should solve your issue!

Note that there currently seems to be an issue on Android, see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16494

I noticed that blurRadius doesn't work either on iOS with RN 0.48, but 0.49.5 (and possibly earlier) is fine. There's no mention of blurRadius in the release notes for 0.48 and 0.49.

Comment: I saw 0.49 Release Note , there is nothing about blurRadius bug fix on Android.

Comment: Hmm, the OP didn't say anything in the question about it being specifically an Android issue. In fact, yes, I get a Red Screen of Death when trying to use blurRadius on Android 7.1 and 7.0. Still, what I wrote is correct - that blurRadius was implemented a few months ago. And it seems that it worked at some point previously for Android. There is an open issue on this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16494